# Service Cloud learning guide

Tags: servicecloud

Please suggest me some good material for learning Service Cloud console basics. I would like to learn about Cases, Entitlements, Assignment Rules..

Answer (score 3):

One of the best resources to learn about service cloud is to take the 'Service Cloud' training in the Help and Training section. This training, I believe, is currently available to paying customers (Premier to be specific).

The use cases and examples used in the training material cover a diverse range of service cloud topics like case management, entitlements, service cloud console etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this question is still relevant, but a Trailhead was recently published, and available here: 
[Service Console Basics](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/service_basics)